# Trying to make nav bar hidden when in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

My navbar currently appears like this when I inspect and put it to a mobile device such as iPhone X: [image: screenshot]

However, I want it to appear like this when in mobile: [image: screenshot]

... and for the bar to open up as it does when the button is clicked.

To get it looking like I want, I use `display:none` in CSS however this then means when you click the button to display it nothing appears. My HTML and CSS is as follows:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

  //Toggles the nav bar
burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

  //animates the links
   navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.getElementsByClassName.animation) {
          link.style.animation = ``;
      } else {
           link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index /7 + 0.5}s`;
      }
   });
   //burger animation
   burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

  });


}

navSlide();
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #5d4954;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        display: none;
    }        
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
}
.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="author" content="Lewis Haddon">
        <title>Business website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/test2.css" type="text/css">
   </head>

   <body>
       <nav>
           <div class="logo">
               <h4>The Nav</h4>
           </div>
           <ul class="nav-links">
               <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="">S3</a></li>
               <li><a href="">RS6</a></li>
           </ul>
           <div class="burger">
               <div class="line1"></div>
               <div class="line2"></div>
               <div class="line3"></div>
           </div>
       </nav>

       <script src="app.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this  for toggler on the right:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     
    </div>
  </nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try to insert your html and jQuery and not css in the above code.

This would be much easier :-)

Comment: bootstrap?? what do i put where star star is i have not used bootstrap

Comment: @tester54321 try now

Comment: this is not the same as i want mine comes from the right hand side

Comment: @tester54321use this in collaboration with your jqery via the script tag in the body section and in youo html

Comment: im new to html and css and dont really know how to take bits of that to fix mine if that makes sense i see that drops the bar from the top however i want it to come from the side

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility: hidden;` as CSS.

You can use the `@media` query to detect whether the client is in used in a mobile environment.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #navID { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

Comment: makes everything disappear on the top line

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your css, you can change the pixel from 320 to 350 or 300 for mobile view

```
@media(max-width: 320px) {
    nav{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: still looks the same when i inspect page on chrome and change device to all different iphone, google pixel etc the bar still stands to the right with a gap above

Comment: try after clearing your cache, also add an id to your `<nav>` like `<nav id="navbar">` and then use the ID in the css to hide it

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c0e831df3eb6227a81d37283b58d0065 i have changed nav-active to show and normal nav is on none so it doesnt appear until i press the button then looks like screenshot however when it isnt showoing before you click it looks like this https://gyazo.com/51a3304cec91abaad7c999525399b125

Comment: when i just manually re size window on my desktop it works as it should its just when i do inspect and device that the issue appears

Answer (score 0):

You could add `overflow: hidden`
and `width: 100%` on your nav.

Also you can set `position: absolute` and `right: -50%` (as your links’ container width is set to 50%). This should work without hidden overflow